# 301 Redirect with separate redirect file (on azure)

Tags: azure, redirect, iis, web-config

I'm trying to redirect an old site urls to a new site using Url Rewrite and placing the url's in a seperate file. I would ideally like to catch all http and https requests. This is what i have in my web.config.

```
<rewrite>
<rewriteMaps configSource="rewritemaps.config" />
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect oldsite.com to newsite.com" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.oldsite.com$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.newsite.com" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

And in my rewritemaps.config file

```
<rewriteMaps>
<rewriteMap name="Redirects">
  <add key="/~woodburningstove/index.php/contacts/" value="/ContactUs" />
  <add key="/about-us" value="/about-us-2" />
  <add key="/blog" value="/blog" />
  <add key="/brands" value="/manufacturer/all" />
  <add key="/brands/herald" value="/herald-stoves" />
  <add key="/brands/stovax" value="/stovax-stoves" />
  <add key="/brands/town-country" value="/town-country-fires"/>
  <add key="/brands/warmglow" value="/warmglow-stoves"/>
  <add key="/brands/warmglow/warmglow-4-cast-iron-stove-flat-black-paint-finish" value="/warmglow-4-black-2"/>
  <add key="/brands/warmglow/warmglow-7-cast-iron-stove-flat-black-paint-finish" value="/warmglow-7-cast-iron-black"/>
  <add key="/brands/warmglow/warmglow-7-cast-iron-stove-flat-ivory-enamel" value="/warmglow-7-cast-iron-ivory-enamel"/>
  <add key="/brands/warmglow/warmglow-7-cast-iron-stove-flat-metallic-black-enamel" value="/warmglow-7-cast-iron-metallic-black-enamel"/>
  <add key="/brands/warmglow/warmglow-7-cast-iron-stove-flat-metallic-black-enamel" value="/warmglow-7-cast-iron-metallic-black-enamel"/>
</rewriteMap>
</rewriteMaps>
```

However i keep getting "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred" but i can't spot what i am doing wrong!?

Answer (score 1):

It was down to having a duplicate entry's in my rewritemaps.config file. The following were listed twice :

```
<add key="/brands/warmglow/warmglow-7-cast-iron-stove-flat-metallic-black-enamel" value="/warmglow-7-cast-iron-metallic-black-enamel"/>
<add key="/brands/warmglow/warmglow-7-cast-iron-stove-flat-metallic-black-enamel" value="/warmglow-7-cast-iron-metallic-black-enamel"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it due to your regex?

Old:

```
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.oldsite.com$" />
```

New:

```
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.oldsite\.com$" />
```

Otherwise I recommend turning custom errors off or doing some remote debugging.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio/